# Incorrect datetime value: '1969-12-31 16:30:00'

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I'm using Spring Boot 2.7.16 with MySQL 8.0.

The MySQL is running with `--default-time-zone=+00:00`.

I have an JPA entity like this,

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "birth_date")
    private OffsetDateTime birthDate;
}
```

which will be created in the database like this,

```
CREATE TABLE `students` (
  `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `birth_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

then I created a repository,

```
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, String> {
}
```

and now here is my unit test,

```
@Test
void verify() {

    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse("02/01/1970", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));
    OffsetDateTime birthDay = localDate.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur")).toOffsetDateTime();

    Student student = new Student();
    student.setId("1");
    student.setBirthDate(birthDay);
    studentRepository.save(student);

    List<Student> students = studentRepository.findAll();
    assertThat(students).hasSize(1);
}
```

the above test with `02/01/1970` was ran successfully and generated the following log,

```
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into students (birth_date, id) values (?, ?)
TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [1970-01-02T00:00+07:30]
TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [1]
```

now I changed the date to `01/01/1970` (one day earlier than `02/01/1970`) like this,

```
@Test
void verify() {

    // everything is the same as above except the date
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse("01/01/1970", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));
    OffsetDateTime birthDay = localDate.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur")).toOffsetDateTime();

    Student student = new Student();
    student.setId("1");
    student.setBirthDate(birthDay);
    studentRepository.save(student);

    List<Student> students = studentRepository.findAll();
    assertThat(students).hasSize(1);
}
```

and the it failed with these logs,

```
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select student0_.id as id1_26_0_, student0_.birth_date as birth_da2_26_0_ from students student0_ where student0_.id=?
TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [1]
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into students (birth_date, id) values (?, ?)
TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [1970-01-01T00:00+07:30]
TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [1]
WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1292, SQLState: 22001
ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '1969-12-31 16:30:00' for column 'birth_date' at row 1
INFO  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl - HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
```

Do you have any idea why it failed with dates earlier than 02/01/1970?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: I linked to a question about timestamp too far in the future, but the same answer applies if the timestamp is too far in the past. Any value outside the supported ranges of timestamp has the same problem.